# Integral of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals, sequence-of-function

Let be $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+nx^3}$ a sequence of functions

Prove:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1}f_n(x) dx =+\infty$$

Comment: You probably mean the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ with $n$ going to infinity, right?

Comment: Say "a sequence".

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry I'm taught in catalan so I didn't know how to say it in English

Comment: This is why I am telling you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that
$$\int_0^1\frac{nx}{1+nx^3}\mathrm{d}x\gt\int_0^1\frac{nx^2}{1+nx^3}\mathrm{d}x=\left[\frac13\ln{\left|1+nx^3\right|}\right]_0^1=\frac13\ln{(1+n)}\to\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

Or $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{nx\,dx}{1+nx^3}\geq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{nx\,dx}{1+nx^2}=\frac{1}{2}\log(n+1). $$
The actual divergence speed is $\sim\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}\sqrt[3]{n}$.